# Using unicode variable names in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I want to use Unicode variable names for writing some math code in Python.

I tried the following

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
α  = 1
β = 3
print α + β
```

But I get the error

```
[~/Desktop]$ python fun.py
  File "fun.py", line 2
    α  = 1
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you on Python 2 or Python 3? If Python 2, get Python 3.

Comment: @user2357112: does that `print α + β` not give enough of a hint to that?

Comment: In Python 2.7 you can have unicode characters but not unicode names.

Comment: @usr2564301: It gives a hint, but only a hint. The same problem could occur on Python 3 with invisible Unicode characters on the alpha line, and parsing wouldn't reach the `print`.

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe you can.. Special characters (with the exception of the underscore and the dollar sign) aren't allowed in variables